# Can FRITZ!Box block Internet access by IP not MAC?

Tags: fritzbox

I have some devices connected to the LAN ports of an old ASUS repeater configured in "media bridge" mode.

The repeater connects over WiFi to a FRITZ!Box 7530 which provides Internet access.

I wish to block one particular device from connecting to the Internet, so I set it to "blocked" in the FRITZ!Box “Internet > Filter > Parental Controls” interface.

However, the FRITZ!Box appears to block by MAC address rather than IP address.

All devices connected behind the repeater appear to the FRITZ!Box to have the repeater’s MAC address, and so all the devices get blocked, instead of just the one I want to block.

*The “Home Network > Network > Network Connections” page shows an active connection corresponding to the repeater's MAC address, whose IP address fluctuates according to the device sending traffic. It seems to be this that is used in the Parental Controls menu.*

How can I configure blocks on the FRITZ!Box by IP address rather than by MAC address?